# Aspose.Words...calculating widt of text in pixels

Tags: text, alignment, words, aspose

I have an MVC3 C# .Net web app.  I am using Aspose.Words to create an MS Word document.  I have a requirement to not include tables in the document.  However, on several lines of the document the alignment of the text is mis-aligned depending on the width of the text.
For example:

This looks good

```
Proposal Name: My Proposal         Date:04/24/2012
```

This does not

```
Proposal Name: My Prop         Date:04/24/2012
```

It should be

```
Proposal Name: My Prop             Date:04/24/2012
```

Based on the width of the first bit of text, I need to calculate the width in pixels (I think) and insert a TAB if necessary.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Graphics.MeasureString function which gives you the width of your string in pixels based on your font. for more info go [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx)

Cheers,

Ehsan

Answer (score 0):

The following code example returns the bounding rectangle of the current entity relative to the page top left corner.

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "in.docx");

LayoutCollector layoutCollector = new LayoutCollector(doc);
LayoutEnumerator layoutEnumerator = new LayoutEnumerator(doc);

foreach (Paragraph para in doc.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Paragraph, true))
{
    var renderObject = layoutCollector.GetEntity(para);
    layoutEnumerator.Current = renderObject;
    RectangleF location = layoutEnumerator.Rectangle;
    Console.WriteLine(location);
}
```

src: https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/541215/replace-run-text-with-string-of-spaces-of-same-pixel-length.aspx